# How to use Descendants and LINQ to get complex XML data to two classes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, lambda

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Script>
<object Id="ID1">
    <Expression>EXPR1</Expression>
    <Result>value="0" action="sleep"</Result>
    <Result>value="1" action="wakeup"</Result>
    <Result>value="2" action="shutdown"</Result>
    <Result>value="3" action="startup"</Result>
</object>
<object Id="ID2">
    <Expression>EXPR2</Expression>
    <Result>value="10" action="sleep"</Result>
    <Result>value="11" action="wakeup"</Result>
    <Result>value="12" action="shutdown"</Result>
    <Result>value="13" action="startup"</Result>
</object>
</Script>
```

I´m trying to grab data to such a class:

```
public class Script

{
     public string Id { get; set; }
     public string Expression { get; set; }
     public List<ScriptItem> Results { get; set; }
}

public class ScriptItem
{
     public string Value { get; set; }
     public string Action { get; set }
}
```

But I´m really confused and messy.

Here is a try example:

```
var list = from item in xmlDoc.Descendants("object")
                   let id = item.Elements("Id")
                   let expression = item.Elements("Expression")
                   let resultlist = item.Elements("Result")
                   where id != null
                   select new Script
                   {
                       ObjectId = id.ToString(),
                       Expression = expression.ToString(),
                       Results = result.ToList()
                   };
```

I´m not expert in Linq and lambda, so appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: Are those Result tags supposed to be attributes?

Comment: Your `Script` object doesn't have an `ObjectId` property...

Comment: Shouldn't your XML look more like this: `<Result><value>10</value> <action>sleep</action></Result>` ?

Comment: bump: The ObjectId needs to be mapped to Id property of Script class. The XML can be changed as well, but I need to fix a format to make it work.

Comment: The main reason your code can't work is that a ToList doesn't convert the types. My answer shows how I'd map them.

Comment: bump: Changing the XML made things easier. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do a couple queries.

```
var objects = xmlDoc.Descendants("object");
var items = 
  objects
    .Select(item => 
      new Script
      {
        Id = item.Attribute("Id").Value,
        Expression = item.Descendant("Expression").Content.Value,
        Results = 
          item
            .Elements("Result")
            .Select(result => 
              new ScriptItem
              {
                Value = result.Attribute("Value").Value,
                Action = result.Attribute("Action").Value
              }
            )
            .ToList()
      }
    );
```

Something like that... assuming you meant the results to be attributes.

Comment: Probably this will need 2 queries. One to get the Script and one to get the Script itens... But can´t make it work.

Comment: I haven't tested this, and wrote it on the spot here assuming the results are supposed to be `<Result value="10" action="sleep" />` form, but it probably will work.

Comment: Helped me to find the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

bump and Alex helped me to find out the way to solution.

The final XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Script>
<Object>
    <Id>ID1</Id>
    <Expression>EXPR1</Expression>
    <Result>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <Action>sleep</Action>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Value>1</Value>
        <Action>wakeup</Action>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Value>2</Value>
        <Action>shutdown</Action>
    </Result>
    <Result>
        <Value>3</Value>
        <Action>startup</Action>
    </Result>
</Object>
</AnimationScript>
```

Then the code:

```
    var objectList = xmlDoc.Descendants("Object")
                    .Select(item => item);

    foreach (var item in objectList)
    {
        string id = item.Element("Id").Value;
        string expression = item.Element("Expression").Value;
        var results = item.Descendants("Result").Select(result => result);

        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            string value = result.Element("Value").Value;
            string action = result.Element("Action").Value;
        }
    }
```

Just need to add moving itens to definitive classes instead of common variables, but tested and seens OK.

Very 'step by step' way so that I can remember this some years from now when looking at the code.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Your selects don't do anything. Select maps an object to another one. Both selects in your code say 'If you see an item, i want it!' You can remove them, or use them instead of a foreach, which is the basis of my answer.